# CMIS Browser : Changing the Versionable Value of CMIS:Document type to Yes

Tags: cmis, cmis-workbench

I am completely new to CMIS Tech. I am trying to change the Versionable Value to Yes for cmis:document type by using the CMIS Workbench.

The only option which I could find is relevant is to click on Update Type, but if you would refer to the attached image it's currently disabled.

Can anyone please suggest an alternative way to change the Versionable value to Yes ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWiBX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "Update Type" button is disabled the repository does not support updating types via CMIS, or does not allow updating this type, or does not allow *you* to update types.

In any case, you have to refer to the documentation of your repository how to change type definitions via a native interface or UI.
The versionable attribute is special, though. If the repository does not support versioning or does not support versioning for this base type you will not be able to change this at all.